# I always get 0 partitions when I call SendMessage(msg). I am specifying 12 via command line

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

### What configuration values are you using for Sarama and Kafka?

Kafka Version: kafka_2.12-1.1.0.tgz
Go Version: 1.9.1

```
package kafka

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
)

var partition = flag.Int("partition", 12, "The partition to produce to.")

func Start_producer(payload []byte) {
    flag.Parse()
    s := "mydata"
    topic := &s
    // brokers := &[]string{"172.25.33.175:9092,172.25.33.176:9092,172.25.33.177:9092"}
    // brokers := []string{"172.25.33.175:9092,172.25.33.176:9092,172.25.33.177:9092"}

    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Producer.RequiredAcks = sarama.WaitForAll
    config.Producer.Retry.Max = 5
    config.Producer.Return.Successes = true
    producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer(strings.Split("172.25.33.175:9092,172.25.33.176:9092,172.25.33.177:9092", ","), config) //default port

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERRR")
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := producer.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    msg := &sarama.ProducerMessage{
        Topic:     *topic,
        Value:     sarama.StringEncoder(payload),
        Partition: int32(*partition),
    }
    fmt.Println("XXXX: ", msg.Partition)
    partition, offset, err := producer.SendMessage(msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("Message is stored in topic(%s)/partition(%d)/offset(%d)\n", *topic, partition, offset)
    fmt.Println("--------------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Println(partition)

}
```

### Problem Description

I am trying to send a stream of messages on to my Kafka broker, I have 3 nodes as specified and I want the messages to be in 12 partitions, but when I call the SendMessage(msg) it returns 0 partitions. Why is that? Why can I not send my messages in partitions?

Answer (score 4):

You have not specified the `ManualPartitioner` in your config, so it will be using the default instead of obeying what you have told it in the partition field.

Add to your config

```
config.Producer.Partitioner = NewManualPartitioner
```

Your partition value should now be obeyed

(Docs : https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#example-Partitioner--Manual)

Comment: I did this step too but it gives me a "panic kafka, partitioner returns an invalid partition index"

Comment: Partitions are zero based as I recall, 12 partitions being 0-11, I'd have to double check the documentation again - you mentioned 12 partitions in the question, so set it to partition 11 for a quick retest

Comment: This is the latest link : https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Shopify/sarama#example-Partitioner-Manual